# Samba and filesystems hang after updates

Tags: filesystem, samba, services, systemd, automount

I have an NTFS samba share that automounts from /etc/fstab.

I recently updated from 4.10.0-33-generic to 4.10.0-35-generic (this may just be a coincidence).

Whenever I restart now, none of my unity desktop icons load (presumably because the config files can't be accessed), can't access samba share, file explorer navigation is extremely slow and sometimes times out--even in non-samba locations.  Even `ls` can be extremely slow.  The samba share reports that it is mounted.  Even unmounting and re-mounting does not solve the issues. Similar behavior between Nautilus and Thunar file managers.

I was poking around in the system and forums looking for a solution when I noticed in `systemctl` output that `media-samba.mount` had failed.

I ran `systemctl status samba` and got [this output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dtdrd.png) instructing me to run `systemctl daemon-reload`, which fixed the problem.  I figured this would fix the issue permanently, but this same hanging behavior persists on repeated boots, and I have to run `systemctl daemon-reload` every time.

Is there something I can fix/edit/update so I don't have to do this every boot?

Comment: I'm a bit confused, you mentioned that you are auto mounting your samba share thanks to /etc/fstab, so using samba a client (not very safe at it may prevent booting your computer if remote share is unavailable). But systemctl status samba command is used to check samba as server. Are you sharing and mounting the share on the same computer?

Comment: Yes, the computer I'm working on is also the samba server.  So the first fstab entry mounts the local partition `/srv/samba/storage` using `ntfs-3g`: ~~ `UUID=(uuid of partition) /srv/samba/storage ntfs-3g auto,users,permissions 0 0` ~~ and then the second fstab entry mounts that location as an actual samba share (using `cifs` as `/media/samba`: ~~ `//192.168.1.112/storage /media/samba cifs rw,suid,dev,noexec,auto,users,async,iocharset=utf8,credentials=/root/.smbcredentials,uid=1000,gid=1002,dir_mode=0770,file_mode=0770,x-systemd.automount 0 0`